# Problem with sampling points vectors on r.sim.water Grass GIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, grass-7.0

I'm trying to run r.sim.water on grass GIS. it works but i don’t get any result on the text file i saved on the variable "logfile". I have tried different vector point for sampling locations. Does the sampling location vector point’s map need any specific characteristics?

What kind of info is supposed to be stored on this text file?

Comment: I have made a test using the example here - also didn't get a log file. Can you please open a bug report? https://grass.osgeo.org/development/bug-tracking/